# SQL Server performance function vs no function

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query (relationship between CONTRACT <-> ORDERS) that I decided to break up into 2 parts (contract and orders) so I can reuse in another stored procedure.

When I run the code before the break up, it took around 10 secs to run; however, when I use a function for getting the contract, then pump the data into a temp table first, then join to the other parts it takes 2m:30s - why the difference in time?

The function takes less than a second to run and returns only one row i.e. details of one contract (contract_id is the parameter supplied to the function).

The part that is most effecting the performance the (ORDERS) largest table in the query has 4.1 million rows and joins to a few other tables however; if I just run the sub query for orders in isolation with a particular filter i.e. the contract id it takes less than a second to run and just happens to return zero records based for the contract I am testing on (due to filtering on the type of order it is looking for).

Base on the above information you would think 1 sec at most for the function + 1 sec at most to get the orders + summarize = 2 seconds at most, not 2 and half minutes!

Where am I going wrong, how do I begin to isolate the issue in time difference?

I know someone is going to tell me to paste the code but surely it is an issue of the database vs indexes perhaps vs how the compiler performs when dealing with raw code versus broken up code into parts. Is there an area of the code I can look at before having to post my whole code as I have tried variations of `OUTER APPLY` vs `LEFT JOIN` from the contract temp table to the orders subquery and both give me about the same result. Any ideas?

Comment: there is a good chance that using a Function instead of a Proc has created a cursor in the logic. try turning on the "include actual execution plan" setting and running both versions. if you see the same coded executed again and again in the one with the function, then it's become a cursor.

Comment: I am not using instead of I am saying if I paste the variations of code into the proc using 1) straight table joins takes around 10 secs to run the proc, versus 2) when I run the proc with a function pumping into a temp table then further down in the proc join the temp table to the subquery the proc takes 2:30.

Comment: This is not enough information to help you... Is the function an *inline TVF* or a *multi-statement* one? How is the JOIN done? If you can apply a filter very early, this might mean to call the function just a few times, while otherwise the function might be called for very many rows, just to throw it away afterwards. Try to check and understand the execution plans... And yes: I'm going to tell you: paste your code :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the issue was with the code but the network I was running it on. Although bizarre in the fact I had 2 versions of the proc running side by side and yesterday or rather before the weekend one was running in 10 secs and it is still running in 10 secs 3 days later and my new version (using the function) was taking anywhere between 2 to 3 minutes. This morning it is running at 2 or 3 seconds!! So I don't know if it is the fact I changed from declaring my table structure and using a table variable instead first to where previously I was using SELECT ... INTO #Contract made the difference or the network or precompiling has an affect. Whatever it is it no longer an issue. Should I delete this post?